# PHP SSH exec() failure: evidently dependent on exported variable size

Tags: php, ssh, tcp, size, exec

I'm sending a rather large string (stored in variable "$data") to a remote server with an SSH command in the format as follows:

```
$command= "ssh -l user subdomain.domain.com bin/prog <<<'$data'";
exec($command, $response, $status);
```

If the data is less than 130KB, the execution behaves normally, and I get the expected response from my server. However, if $data is greater than about 130KB, the execution of the command immediately returns a NULL array as a response.

I'm not too sure what's happening here. At first I suspected it was a time-out issue, but the command fails *immediately* if $data is past a certain size. Evidently the only determining factor here appears to be the size of $data. It takes about 30-35 seconds to execute the command when the data is less than 130KB.

Any input is appreciated. If more information is required, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core issue here had to do with the `exec()` function buffer.

The command we were executing to send data via SSH via `exec()` was essentially an incredibly long string. PHP has a string size limit of around 2GB. While SSH itself appears to be able to transmit an arbitrary amount of data, our `exec()'`s buffer appears to fail around 130KB. Under these assumptions, we used a PHP function called `proc_open()`:

```
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("file", "/tmp/error-output.txt", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
);

$cwd = '/tmp';
// $env = array('some_option' => 'aeiou');      // Our environment variables are loaded in the shell on login.
$env = NULL; 
$process = proc_open('ssh -l user subdomain.domain.com bin/prog', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    // $pipes now looks like this:
    // 0 => writeable handle connected to child stdin
    // 1 => readable handle connected to child stdout
    // Any error output will be appended to /tmp/error-output.txt

    foreach($dataset as $dataline){
        fwrite($pipes[0], $dataline . "\n"); // Feed data down the pipe
    }

    fclose($pipes[0]);

    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]); // echo out the reply from the bin/prog
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    // It is important that you close any pipes before calling
    // proc_close in order to avoid a deadlock
    $return_value = proc_close($process);

    echo "command returned $return_value\n";
}
```

This procedure is straight out of the manual.